# Self-contradictory combinations, are my explanations correct?

Tags: voltage, current, current-source, short-circuit, voltage-source

- Can a current source be in parallel with a short circuit?
- Can a current source be in series with an open circuit?
- Can a voltage source be in parallel with a short circuit?

I have added my own answers and am confused about those a little bit.

---

For the first one, as a short circuit has zero voltage and infinite current, the voltage of current source must be the same as that of the short circuit right? If the current source has no voltage, how can charge even flow?

For the second one, as in series, the components must have similar current to the components in series with it. As in open circuit there is no current, this is not possible for what I think.

For the third one, a short circuit has no voltage and infinite current. As in parallel, the voltage of the voltage source must be equal to that of the short circuit, which is not possible as the short circuit's voltage is zero. So this circuit is also not possible right?

Comment: Hi, You can't ask *questions* in an *answer* so your (non-)answer has been added into the question as an update. Please do not write anything in the box below labeled "Your Answer" unless you are writing a new full & final answer which is the solution for your question, and the topic can be closed. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you are thinking of ideal current sources and ideal voltage sources.  Is that the case?

Comment: Yes,  I am talking about ideal sources here.

Comment: the answers to your three questions are all  `yes` ... you can connect the current sources and voltage sources any way you like .... perhaps you actually wanted to ask `what would happen if .... ?`

Comment: The question in my book is actually:
Which of the following are self-contradictory combinations of circuit elements?
a. A 12V voltage source in parallel with a 2A current source. 
b.A 2A current source in series with a 3A current source. 
c.A 2A current source in parallel with a short circuit.
d.A 2A current source in series with an open circuit. 
e.A 5V Voltage source in parallel with a short circuit. 
@jsotola

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming ideal elements

1. A current source can without any problem be in parallel with a short.
   That's because a current source just delivers the intended current. The voltage is a function of the series resistance (which is 0 Ohm resulting in 0 V for the voltage)

The rest is OK.

Answer (score 3):

> (1)...a short circuit has zero voltage and infinite current, the voltage
> of current source must be the same as that of the short circuit right?
> If the current source has no voltage, how can charge even flow?

More correct: **a short circuit has zero voltage** across its ends - it allows *any* and *all* current to flow. Your idea here is correct - the short circuit forces a parallel current source terminals to zero volts. All its current flows easily in that short circuit.
A current source's natural state is feeding a short circuit...since there's zero voltage, no power is dissipated.

> (2)...in series, the components must have similar current to the
> components in series with it. As in open circuit there is no current,
> this is not possible for what I think.

Yes, a current source demands that current must flow. One must ask where else this current goes, since a series circuit has at least one open end. If there's no path back to the current source for current to return, then there must exist in that series circuit an infinite voltage, likely across the current source terminals...something is going to break down...likely the current source.

> (3)...a short circuit has no voltage and infinite current. As in
> parallel, the voltage of the voltage source must be equal to that of
> the short circuit, which is not possible as the short circuit's
> voltage is zero. So this circuit is also not possible right?

Right.
 The short circuit *allows* infinite current, and demands zero volts. The voltage source cannot supply infinite current, but desires its voltage. This is not a comfortable state for a voltage source. Its most natural state feeds an open circuit, where no power is dissipated because no current flows.

Two results are possible in the voltage source -> short circuit scenario:

- voltage source overheats from too much current, breaks down
- short circuit (having some finite resistance) overheats and goes open-circuit, like a fuse.

Answer (score 2):

Your questions are good ones, but the scenarios you propose are not practical. There's no such thing as a short circuit, really, since everything has some resistance. There's no voltage or current source capable of producing infinite current, either, so questions like "what happens when you short-circuit a voltage source?" are always answered with "it depends on the source, and the nature of the short-circuit".

This is the electrical equivalent of the physics question "what happens when an irresistible force meets an immovable object?". In theory, if such things were possible, the energies involved would be so great as to literally flirt with black holes and defy any means we have of describing, explaining or even perceiving the consequences.

Practically speaking, you *can* build very good current and voltage sources, and extremely low resistance conductors, but in the end the answers will always be something like "the current that would flow is whatever the source *can* supply, or whatever the attempted short-circuit permits".

The answer to every single one of your questions is "yes, you can do that" and the best I can do is tell you, for each case, what a *real life* source would do under the circumstances you propose:

1. **Short circuit a current source**. Current sources can be thought of as variable voltage sources that adjust their potential difference to whatever value is necessary (called the compliance voltage) to produce exactly the specified current through whatever's connected to them, according to Ohm's law. It's incorrect to say that current sources have no voltage across them.
   A short-circuit will never have zero resistance in reality, and there will always be some non-zero potential difference that a current source can apply across that "load", to produce current through it according to Ohm's law. Consequently, nothing special happens when you short-circuit a current source. It simply produces a very small potential difference, exactly enough to cause the right amount of current to flow.
2. **Connect nothing to a current source**. Two outcomes that I can think of:

   - The current source develops its maximum compliance voltage, but that voltage is insufficient to cause breakdown of the medium between its terminals, and no (or negligible) current flows.
   - The compliance voltage developed by the source is sufficient to cause the medium (such as air) between its terminals to break down and begin conducting. If the medium is gas, that's a spark caused by ionisation of the gas molecules. It's also a sudden decrease in resistance between the source's terminals, and the compliance voltage will fall, until it's no longer sufficient to sustain the breakdown/ionised state of the medium, and conduction ceases. Compliance voltage rises again, and the process repeats.
3. **Short-circuit a voltage source**. This scenario is the most likely to occur in circuits, and involves two resistances; the internal resistance of the source, and the resistance of the supposed "short-circuit". There are two likely outcomes:

   - The source's own internal resistance is small compared to the short-circuit resistance, and it develops negligible voltage across it. Consequently the source is able to provide its full EMF across the short-circuit, and a huge current flows, determined chiefly by this external resistance. All or most of the energy is delivered to the external short-circuit load. If that load is able to dispose of this energy more quickly than it receives it, the short-circuit survives, the source survives and all is well, if a bit hot. Otherwise the short-circuit melts, and opens, and current stops flowing.
   - The short-circuit resistance is small compared to the source's internal resistance. In this case most of the source's EMF is applied across its own internal resistance, which will limit the (enormous) current that flows, and which will receive all/most of the energy. If the source is able to continue operating when it's hot, and is able to somehow get rid of that heat quicker than it receives it, then everything survives. Otherwise the source overheats (and possible catches fire) and eventually ceases to provide energy electrically, at which point current stops flowing. And your house is gone.

There are no doubt other subtle variations on these outcomes, but those are the obvious ones.